# How do I view a Rackspace backup circa 2013?

Tags: linux, backup, redhat, mac-osx, rackspace

I was a Rackspace customer until 2013. When I shut down my server, I had them send me a backup of it on a hard drive. Recently I had someone ask for something on that server, so I got the hard drive from my safe deposit box and plugged it in. It's a WD Passport that connects via USB.

The original server was RHEL. I'm not entirely sure what version, but I'm hoping that doesn't matter wildly.

I'm currently trying to view it on Mac OSX 1.9 using FUSE for OSX and `fuse-ext2`.

When I mount the drive I see /boot, but it only contains about 9MB of data. I suspect that I'm just viewing this incorrectly in some way.

Here is a manifest of the files on the drive:

[image]

As you can see, none of the files are really over 1.5MB. The original server had over 100GB of data. Interestingly, I shut down the server in 2013 and I don't see any modified dates here that are that recent.

The Rackspace support folks have informed me that they cannot help me as I closed the account so many years ago.

I suspect that there is just another partition on the drive that my computer isn't seeing.

Here's an image of my disk utility:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Plug the drive into a Linux machine. Mac OS X cannot deal with the LVM volumes that are most likely on there.

Comment: what Michael said, or use a linux VM and share the USB drive with it.  i.e. virtualbox.

Comment: Michael - can you make that an answer so I can accept it?